# ROR can't connect remotely to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to establish_connection to database on other machine:

```
require 'mysql2'
require "active_record"
```

## Using ActiveRecord

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter=> 'mysql2',
:database=> 'development_db',
:host=> "192.168.1.135",
:port=> "3306",
:username=> 'username',
:password=>'password'
)
```

get following error :
Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.135' (111) (Mysql2::Error)

Comment: Is the mysql server configured to allow remote connections?

Comment: Do you have the permission to connect to the IP address you are trying to access.

Comment: permission, no how to give permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too much hard work i found following was configuration missing to connect remote datadase.

1. Add following lines to my.cnf in mysqld section

   bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
2. Restart mysql service
3. run following commands(create new user and password)

   GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO u_name@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;